# У меня есть двумерный массив типа char и есть функция в которую нужно передать элементы этого массива передать. Расскажите как это сделать

Tags: c

Есть массив:

```
char arr[][5] = {{"Apple"},{"Kiwi"},{Mango}};
```

Нужно передать его в функцию, которая будет считать количество строк в этой массиве:

```
int func(...)
{
    ...
}
```

Вопрос в том, как реалезовать такую функцию и как передать в неё такой массив?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, при передаче в функцию массива строк заранее неизвестной длины, используется следующий приём:

1. В конец массива (списка) строк добавляется ещё один элемент - указатель NULL.
2. В функции организуется цикл по списку строк.
3. Цикл заканчивается, когда очередной элемент массива строк (типа char *) имеет значение NULL.